# CakePHP 3.0 - Pass parameters to mapped RESTful resource

Tags: php, rest, routes, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to generate a route in CakePHP 3. I have a controller called `ContractsController`, and within that I have an action - `details($id)`.

I want to map the `details($id)` action to:

`/api/contracts/details/id.json`

I have gotten as far as the following (in `routes.php`):

```
Router::scope('/api', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json']);
    $routes->resources('Contracts', [
        'map' => [
            'details' => [
                'action' => 'details',
                'method' => 'GET'
            ]
        ]
    ]);
});
```

This allows me to access the `details` action through `/api/contracts/details.json` but I can't figure out how to pass an id with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I was able to solve this with the following:

```
Router::scope('/api', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json']);
    $routes->resources('Contracts', [
        'map' => [
            'details/:id' => [
                'action' => 'details',
                'method' => 'GET'
            ]
        ]
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this is working in CakePHP 3. Also, if you're passing strings as arguments, use * wildcard instead of ':id' so that the fifth line in the above example would read `'details/*'`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
Router::scope('/api', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json']);
    $routes->resources('Contracts', [
        'map' => [
            'details' => [
                'action' => 'details',
                'id' => '[0-9]+',
                'method' => 'GET'
            ]
        ]
    ]);
});
```

If this does not work, let me know and I will run a quick test.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay following this up. This still gives me the same error message: `Error: ApiController could not be found.`, which I think means that the URL just isn't being detected as something that needs to be routed.

Comment: That is indeed strange. However, you may want to take a look at your `routes.php` setup. You may want to post your entire code from that file here. I think the issue is there.